# Configure XFCE startup commands in NixOS

Tags: xfce, window-manager, nixos, xinit

In NixOS, `services.xserver.desktopManager.xfce.extraSessionCommands` describes "Shell commands executed just before XFCE is started.". What about for shell commands right *after* XFCE is started?

That is, I want to persist in my `configuration.nix` file what I would normally put in an `.xinitrc`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put most of the application you would usually put into xinitrc also into `services.xserver.desktopManager.xfce.extraSessionCommands`
as important environment variables such as `$DISPLAY` and `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` are set. 
In fact in most xinitrc's start the window manager as the last process.

Here is a snippet how `extraSessionCommands` is implemented taken from [xfce.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/x11/desktop-managers/xfce.nix#L123):

```
services.xserver.desktopManager.session = [{
  name = "xfce";
  bgSupport = true;
  start = ''
    ${cfg.extraSessionCommands}
    # Set GTK_PATH so that GTK+ can find the theme engines.
    export GTK_PATH="${config.system.path}/lib/gtk-2.0:${config.system.path}/lib/gtk-3.0"
    # Set GTK_DATA_PREFIX so that GTK+ can find the Xfce themes.
    export GTK_DATA_PREFIX=${config.system.path}
    ${pkgs.runtimeShell} ${pkgs.xfce.xinitrc} &
    waitPID=$!
  '';
}];
```